# License information for using the code posted in site

Tags: discussion, licensing

Are you able to tell me what the license terms are for code posted on this website. For example what are the license terms for this code :

[Computer specific ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423454/computer-specific-id)

We are using the code snippets for getting the computer serial number from the above site.

Answer (score 2):

From the footer of each and every site:

> user contributions licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

If a user has added a disclaimer / cited the source of the code, the terms of the original are those that apply.